# PowerShell - How do I call a variable with another variable?

Tags: powershell, indirection

I have this code:

```
$var_Cart="text cart"
$var_Cat="text cat"
$var_Home="text home"

$names = "Cart","Cat","Home"
foreach ($name in $names)
{
    $variable="var_$name"
    Write-Host "`n`-----Print "$variable"-----"
}
```

how can i get to print "text cart, text cat and text home"?

NOTE: In BASH resolve like this: ${!var}

Comment: `Get-Variable`.

Comment: While `Get-Variable` would do, better use a hash table or a PSCustomObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the value property of get-variable:

```
$var_Cart = 'text cart'
$var_Cat = 'text cat'
$var_Home = 'text home'

$names = 'Cart','Cat','Home'
foreach ($name in $names)
{
  (get-variable var_$name).value
}
```

output

```
text cart
text cat
text home
```

Comment: Nice, though it's simpler and more efficient to use the `-ValueOnly` switch if all you're interested in is the variable's value: `Get-Variable -ValueOnly var_$name`.

Comment: Thank you very much @js2010, I solved it

Answer (score 3):

Consider (probaply) better alternatves:

```
$Hash=@{Cart="text cart";Cat="text cat";Home="text home"}
$var = [PSCustomObject]$hash

$hash

$var

$names = "Cart","Cat","Home"
foreach ($name in $names){
    "`$hash['{0}']={1}" -f $name,$hash[$name]
    "`$var.{0}={1}" -f $name,$var.$name
}
```

Sample output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Cart                           text cart
Cat                            text cat
Home                           text home

Cart      Cat      Home
----      ---      ----
text cart text cat text home    

$hash['Cart']=text cart
$var.Cart=text cart
$hash['Cat']=text cat
$var.Cat=text cat
$hash['Home']=text home
$var.Home=text home
```

With this approach(es) you also don't need to know the names beforehand,
you can iterate them with:

```
$hash.Keys
```

or

```
$var.PSObject.Properties.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Invoke-Expression`. This command evaluates a string and runs it as a command. See the Microsoft Docs for detailed information [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6).

```
$var_Cart="text cart"
$var_Cat="text cat"
$var_Home="text home"

$names = "Cart","Cat","Home"
foreach ($name in $names)
{
    $variable="`$var_{0}" -f $name
    Write-Host "`n-----Print $variable-----"
    Invoke-Expression -Command $variable
}
```

Otherwise, as Bacon_Bits suggested, you can use `Get-Variable`. For this option you need to exclude the `$`-sign and forward just the name. I selected only the Value, otherwise you get a table with Name and Value.

```
foreach (...)
{
    $var2="var_{0}" -f $name
    (Get-Variable -Name $variable).Value
}
```

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)